# Android Firestore HashMap cannot be cast to Object

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I try to get data from `Firebase` and store it in a `ArrayList<Object>`. To do so I created this method:

```
private void getWholeListObject(int i, SellerObject soa) {
    String userid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("Users").document(userid);



 // Get the document, forcing the SDK to use the offline cache
    docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                // Document found in the offline cache
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();

                ArrayList<ShoppingListObject>shoppingLists = new ArrayList<>();
                shoppingLists = (ArrayList<ShoppingListObject>) document.get("shoppingLists");
                Log.i("asdf", "addNewDataToList: "+shoppingLists.get(i).getProducts());
               addNewDataToList(i, shoppingLists, soa);
            } else {

            }
        }
    });

}
```

The error occurs at the log.

Here is my `Object` class:

```
public class ShoppingListObject {
    String listname;
    ArrayList<String> products;

    public ShoppingListObject() {
    }

    public ShoppingListObject(String listname, ArrayList<String> products) {
        this.listname = listname;
        this.products = products;
    }

    public String getListname() {
        return listname;
    }

    public void setListname(String listname) {
        this.listname = listname;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(ArrayList<String> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
}
```

please find attached my `Firestore` structure:

[image: Database structure]

Comment: You can't just cast some field from a document into any object you like.  You will need to write some code to convert it.

Comment: why ? its the same structure or not? If i try to get values into a custom object it works as well

Comment: No, it's not the same structure.  The SDK will give you back primitive types, Lists, or Maps.  Examine the content in a debugger to see for yourself.  You can't cast a Map or List to something else.

Comment: The SDK can actually also give you an object of a custom class, but only for the entire `DocumentSnapshot` at once, not for individual fields. See [`DocumentSnapshot.toObject()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.html#toObject(java.lang.Class%3CT%3E))

Comment: Will it be helpful for you, if I'll provide you  an answer on how to get the `products` ArrayList<String> using an object of the `ShoppingListObject` class or even directly from the property? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo, i solved this problem by storing the data in an ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> thanks to all of you